# Running Polymer/Mocha HTML tests with IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, polymer, karma-mocha

Is it possible to have IntelliJ run Polymer's unit tests?  They have plugins for Mocha and Karma, but how to use them with these HTML based tests is non-obvious.

Comment: Please vote for IDEA-142833 Support wct (web-components-tester) in Polymer 1.0 plugin: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-142833

Answer (score 1):

Polymer Team has created a tool called `web-components-tester` which is built on top of `Mocha` and `Chai`. But I am not sure how this too might be compatable with `IntelliJ`.

Below is a simple test:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="../../webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../../web-component-tester/browser.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="../awesome-element.html">
</head>
<body>
  <awesome-element id="fixture"></awesome-element>
  <script>
    suite('<awesome-element>', function() {
      test('is awesomest', function() {
        assert.isTrue(document.getElementById('fixture').awesomest);
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

More resource about testing Polymer elements at:
https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/articles/unit-testing-elements.html
https://github.com/Polymer/web-component-tester 
https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/resources/tooling-strategy.html
https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/polymer/debugging.html

Comment: Please vote for IDEA-142833 Support wct (web-components-tester) in Polymer 1.0 plugin: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-142833

Answer (score 0):

Please vote for:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-142833

> **IDEA-142833 Support wct (web-components-tester) in Polymer 1.0 plugin.**
>
> Polymer 1.0 default way of testing web components is via a tool called
>   web-components-tester (or wct) which is built on top of Mocha (as a
>   test framework), Chai assertions, Async, Lodash, Sinon and sinon-chai.
>   Some more info:
>
> • https://github.com/Polymer/web-component-tester   •
>   https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit/blob/master/README.md
>
> The Polymer and Web Components Plugin could:
>     - Make all this install and just work.
>     - By default, wct tests on all installed browsers. We should be able to select the browsers to test from IntelliJ debug window.
>     - Output from wct could be presented in a readable way in IntelliJ debug window, just like JUnit tests.